# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword not working as well

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting problems when try to login with an registered email in signInWithEmailAndPassword Firebase method in JavaScript. I know that the problem is with the fields required, but i don't know how to fix it. Here is my snipet

```
        <form>
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus="autofocus" required="required">
          <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"     id="btnLogin">Login</button>
        </form>

  <script>
  $('#btnLogin').click(function(){

  var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
  var password = $('#inputPassword').val();

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);         
        }
            console.log(error);
    }); 
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    alert("User is signed in");
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    alert("No user is signed in");
  }
});
</script>
</body>
```

This was to be the original code that does not work (it gives me the message "No user is signed in"), but if I force a validation error (for example leave the fields empty and put the value directly in the variables), it gives seconds and returns the message "User is signed in"

```
var email = "a@a.com";
var password = "123456";

//var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
//var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
```

Another way I forced to give the error and it worked was putting an input hidden and required. In that case I returned an error in the console, but after a few seconds I received the message "User is signed in". The code of input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputHidden" required="required" hidden>
```

The error:

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.

ReferenceError: email is not defined
at Object.next (login.html:135)
at subscribe.ts:104
at subscribe.ts:225
```

Comment: That sounds like if you'd `console.log(email`);` and `console.log(password);`, they would log different values than the hardcoded ones. Can you try that? If that is indeed the code, the problem has nothing to do with Firebase, and you probably want to search for how to get values from inputs with jQuery. I don't immediately see what'd be going wrong there, but it'd at least determine the direction of where to search further.

Comment: Frank, I will edit my post with the tests I've tried. It looks like the problem is with the validation of html5

Comment: Are you able to see the user details after sign in, in your firebase console?
Also, did you try printing the email and password before calling the firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) method?

Comment: I've tried , but I can not see user information, neither in alert (), nor in console.log